# How to set change log entries user in Dynamics Nav 2016

Tags: c#, odata, microsoft-dynamics, navision, dynamics-nav

I've written some code to query the ODATA endpoint in Dynamics Nav 2016. I did this by creating an [ODATA connected service](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b343d0eb-6493-44c2-b558-13a0408d013f). I wrote the following code to add a record:

```
var navision = new Navision(
    new Uri("http://navision:7048/navision/OData/Company('Company1')"))
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("MyUser@example.com", "password")
};
navision.AddToFoo(new Foo() { Name = "Bar" });
navision.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I have enabled 'Change Log Entries' for the `Foo` table. However, when the above code executes, the user displayed in the change log entries is `MyUser@example.com`. Is it possible to set this user myself explicitly?

Comment: Erm... Change credentials! What’s the problem exactly?

Comment: There is no standard way to do it if you really want the answer. You can develop everything though.

Comment: My company is exposing Nav tables in one of their API's to an Android app. Those users do not have Nav credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way to do this kind of substitution. Change log entry is created as follows. `USERID` is system function that will return logged in user name.

`ChangeLogEntry."User ID" := USERID;`

If you can have a development on your system then you need to change `navision.AddToFoo(new Foo() { Name = "Bar" });` to something like `navision.AddToFoo(new Foo() { Name = "Bar", ChangedBy = "RealUserName"});` and have this field added to table Foo. This will at least allow you to see last user that changed the record.